# How to clear a textbox on single press of Backspace key using Javascript?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, datepicker

I m working on a web application that contains a text box. The value of text box is filled from Date picker and its property is read only by default. till now everything is working fine. But problem occurs when I press backspace button. Rather than clearing the text box it is redirecting me back on the previous page.

i handled this situation by a javascript function by referring some previous answers on this site.

```
 function allowBackSpace(val) {
    var keyCodeEntered = (event.which) ? 
                             event.which : 
                             (window.event.keyCode) ? 
                                 window.event.keyCode : 
                                 -1;
    if (keyCodeEntered == 8) {
        $(this).val(""); 
        return true;
    }
    return false;
   }
```

**UPDATE :** this function is called from

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtDate" 
             Style="margin-left: 5px; margin-right: 5px" 
             runat="server"
             Width="88px" 
             onkeypress="return allowBackSpace(this);">
</asp:TextBox>
```

I m calling this function on key press event of the textbox. The preoblem is that it is allowing only to delete one character at a time.

I wish to clear the whole textbox if user presses backspace button. Stuck here as how to achieve this.

Thanks in advance
Akhil

> PS:Any way to achieve this using C# code will also be very helpful.

Comment: can you post some explanation of this code? For instance, what is the argument `val`?

Comment: Have you tried giving the focus back to that textbox ?

Comment: sometimes backspace event is depend on browser compatibility..which browser you are using??

Comment: @JohnnBlade No I didnt tried that. Can you explain this with some code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are returning true from js function, which also performs its keypress event. So, try with returning false.
You can try the following code:

> function allowBackSpace(val)  {
>
> ```
> var keyCodeEntered = 
>      (event.which) ? event.which : 
>                  (window.event.keyCode) ? window.event.keyCode : -1;
> if (keyCodeEntered == 8) 
> {
>      $(this).val("");
>      return false;
>  }
>  return false; }
> ```

Comment: sorry no use. I have attached debugger to this function as well. Its not even calling the javascript function on backspace or dlelete button press.

Answer (score 1):

Try this function.

```
 $("#txt1").keydown(function(eve){
    var keyCodeEntered = eve.keyCode? eve.keyCode : eve.charCode;

    if (keyCodeEntered == 8) 
    {
         $(this).val("");
         return false;
     }
     return false;
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Use Jquery

```
$("#txtDate").keyup(function(event){
    if(event.keyCode == 8){
        $("#txtDate").val("");
        return false;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function allowBackSpace(e,obj)
{
    var evt=e||window.event;
    if(evt.keyCode==8)
    {
        obj.value='';
    }
}
```

Now, use `onkeydown` event instead of onkeypress

```
<textarea onkeydown='allowBackSpace(event,this)'></textarea>
```